# Get SQL Function(?)

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I inherited this query from someone else that has a Get function(?) inside the Case function. It goes something like

```
Case 
    when a.date = a.entrancedate
        then 
            (case 
                 when database.dbo.Get(columnname, I am assuming)= "x value" then "y value")
```

I can't anything anywhere about that `Get` function (?) - can anyone shed some light on how to use it or where I can find information on it?

I haven't tried anything because I can't find anything on the issue.

Comment: could be a user defined function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/user-defined-functions?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: It's this. Much appreciated!